# Access express post method from with react component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

Basically I am creating a email form with react as view and express for the server. It is working fine.

Instead of redirecting on success I am just wanting to re render the form component on the contact page.

Is there anyway I can access the post request success value from within a react component? maybe calling a fetch method within the contact component that fetchs at the '/contact' end point? will this trigger the app.post() method within my express.js file??

this is my post request on button submit within react:

```
handleFormSubmit = (name, email, text) => {

  axios.post('/contact', {
   name: name,
   email: email,
   text: text
  }).then(res => {
   this.setState({sent: true})
   console.log(this.state);
  }).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
  })
}
```

this is my express js post:

```
server.post('/contact', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    sendMail(req.body).then(info => console.log(info))

    // I am getting a response here just fine
    console.log(res)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('express line 25: ', error);
  }

});
```

I am using Next.js and nodemailer with GMail

Thanks

Comment: Is the express server running? Is the request from the front-end to `/contacts` in the backend succeeding (passing)? May you please upload, at least the server code and the component's?

Comment: But is the server running? And is the request reaching  the the server?

Comment: server is running fine, im getting a response from the server that is logging to the terminal after the post has been sent and gotten a response. Email is arriving fine in the mail box, just not getting a response to the front even axios.post method

Comment: Cool. May you please update your question with the front-end code thats initiating the request?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your code, but if we use fetch inside a React component, try using `componentDidMount`:

```
class Contact extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {data: null, isLoading: true}; 
  }

  // from the server 
  componentDidMount() {
      fetch('/contact').then( response =>  response.json()
      ).then( data => {
          this.setState({data, isLoading: false}); // es6 syntax same as this.setState({data: data, isLoading: false})
      }).catch( err => {
          throw new Error(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
     const {data, isLoading} = this.state;  
     if(isLoading){return (<div>Loading...</div>)} //no data fetched in  the initial render 
      return (
          <div>
            {data}
          </div> 
     );
  }
}
```

Hopefully that will help you.

Comment: i have this same setup but using axios instead of fetch, i want to do it on form submit, so running a function when button is submitted, not getting a response back even though the email is being sent. Whats the benefit of sending it in componentDidMount ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry guys, problem has nothing to do with any code, its next js setup, i built it and ran and seems to be returning fine!